# Reset selected checkbox when toggle off using angular2 and ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am using Angular2 and ionic2 for my application. Here, I am having a toggle.When toggle is off, I should not allow users to select checkbox. It is working fine for me.Problem is when I select the checkbox while toggle is on and if I turn it off again those checkboxes which are selected should get reset.

Can any one help me out how to achieve this?

My code lies below
**app.html**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-item class="toggle">
    <ion-label>App Explore</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle class="center" [(ngModel)]="exploreOn" (ionChange)="toggleChange()"></ion-toggle>
</ion-item>
<div class="urban">        
          <div class="ck-button" *ngFor="let slide of tags; let i = index">             
        <label>                 
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" [disabled]="checkboxDisabled" [(ngModel)]="selectname">
            <span>{{slide.tag}} </span>
        </label>
    </div>        
</div>
```

**app.ts**

```
export class AppPage {
selectname: boolean = false;
exploreOn: boolean = false;
checkboxDisabled = true;
checkboxEnabled = false;
public posts: any;
tags: any;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {    
this.http.get('./mockAPI/chatList.json').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.posts = data.json();
    this.tags = this.posts.tags;
    console.log("data", this.tags);
  });
}
toggleChange() {   
  if (this.exploreOn != true) {
  this.checkboxDisabled = true;     
  this.selectname = false;
 }    
 else  {
  this.checkboxDisabled = false;
  }
}

**My josn file lies below**
 "tags": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "tag": "#jetset"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "tag": "#retailtherapy"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "tag": "#eatsipgroove"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ion-checkbox](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/) instead.

```
<ion-checkbox value="1" [disabled]="checkboxDisabled" [(ngModel)]="selectname" [checked]="isChecked">
```

and in component

```
toggleChange() {   
  if (this.exploreOn != true) {
  this.checkboxDisabled = true;  
this.isChecked= false;   //reset checkbox
  this.selectname = false;
 }    
 else  {
  this.checkboxDisabled = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: If i clicked on a single checkbox, it is selecting all checkboxes together. I think ngModel consider all checkbox  with unique id.

Comment: you will have to give different ngModels for each as it is 2 way binding

Comment: I am rendering those checkbox from json array, How can i give diffrent ngModels for each. I am new in angular2, can u explain how can i get this done this case

Comment: you could make selectedname an array  and traverse it..[(ngModel)]=selectedName[i]

Comment: Thanks...it works.. but while toggle off, checkbox is getting disabled instead of clearing that

Comment: `[disabled]="checkboxDisabled"` takes care disabling,  `[checked]="isChecked" ` is for checked or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131146/discussion-between-annmary-and-suraj-rao).

Answer (score 0):

just add `(click)="function()"` in your selectname row.
check this code
declare a variable called it filter

```
filter: boolean= false;
```

then use ngModel in html part to access and assign its value.

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="filter" (click)="filterData()">
```

it will call a function filterData() which you can use to do all your functionality

```
filter(){
  this.filter = !this.filter;// this will change value of it true and false 
}
```

for more checkbox you can use declare more variable like filter1: boolean

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: add console.log in you function. i am using this method its working for me. or show your code plukr